# Symmetrized armature keeps appearing on the same side as the armature that I wanted to symmetrize

Tags: armature

I tried to symmetrize my .l(left) bones onto the right. When I do, the names flip but the position doesn't flip, the .r bones are on the same side as the .l bones.

[image]

Comment: Share your file. https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That symmetrize function always works along the X axis, not Y.

Rotate the character and the rig 90 degrees along Z axis, apply (Ctrl A) rotations of both, then continue the rigging process using the symmetrize function.

Comment: It worked, thanks.